# Image size not defined in Javascript / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, url, size, image

I'm having problems finding the width and height of an image. I'm trying to pass it to the URL so I can set it as a PHP session variable.

```
location.href="homeview.php?x=" + dd.elements.image1.x + "&y=" + dd.elements.image1.y + "&h=" + document.getElementById('image1').height;
```

the URL reads as such with an example image:

```
homeview.php?x=8&y=8&h=undefined
```

so I've tried

```
location.href="homeview.php?x=" + dd.elements.image1.x + "&y=" + dd.elements.image1.y + "&h=" + dd.elements.image1.height;
```

and its still undefined, my img tags are like this

```
<img id="image1" src="newimages/image1.png" width="45" height="45">
```

If it helps, the Javascript is run in a function at the bottom of the page. Any advice would help.

Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
document.getElementById('image1').offsetHeight;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight